# how to upload large mysql table to a remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, web, hosting, web-hosting, mysql-workbench

i have a large 1.3 gb sql table that i want to upload to a remote mysql server, the problem is, that mysql server supports a live website and i don't want to hamper the performance of that server , how to do it.
FYI : there are 4 million records in the table.

here my main concern is the performance of webserver, since we run a live site on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do :

1. A **mysqldump** command to export data
2. Compress the data (usually more than 90% compression)
3. Send this archive via sftp on your server
4. Uncompress the archive
5. A **mysql** command to import data

If you have to do it on a daily basis, then a cron task on both servers.

Comment: what about performance of live server, is it fine to upload 
the whole table in one single step using, 
mysql -u username -p -D dbname < tableName.sql

Comment: This is def the best way. The time to completion will be alot shorter, so you can schedule or execute the reimport once the load is not so much.

Comment: Yes. 4 Millions rows are not so heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your sql request into your server and do a cron to execute it when there is not a lots of people on our site.